# Bind <mat-select> form value dynamically

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a 'div' where I am using a "mat-select". Inside which I have countryList dropdown in multi-select format.

My task is, on a button click I want to auto-populate the country within the "mat-select".

```html
<div class="col-sm-5">
   <mat-form-field style="width: 372px;">
     <mat-label>Select your options</mat-label>
     <mat-select formControlName="origin" [(value)]="selected" multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countryLists" [value]="country">{{ country }}</mat-option>
   </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, and what did you try so far? What is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <mat-form-field style="width: 372px;">
    <mat-label>Select your options</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="origin" [(value)]="selected" multiple>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countryLists" [value]="country">{{ country }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button (click)="populate()" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Populate</button>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
  countryLists: string[] = [];
  selected: any;


  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  populate(): any {
    this.countryLists = ['SriLanka', 'India', 'England'];
  }
```